# Is it possible to submit a piece of software architecture in stackoverflow and ask for peer review?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I enjoy a lot stack over flow. I learned a lot of stuff here while I was beginning android programming, it is from far my favorite forum for java & android. I love the design of this programmer's site and believe there are quite a lot of good coders around.

So, I'd like to submit some code, or sometimes a piece of software architecture in a question or article and ask for reviews and contributions to make it better.

Is it possible to use stack over flow this way ?

Thanks all folks,
 Stéphane

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is what you want

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

possible but not recommended. codereview.stackexchange.com is for that. and this question actually belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com